# Why the std::is_array in template function is not distinguishing between int and array type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits, function-templates

In the following code, I am using a template function and type traits to distinguish between an integer type (else case) and array type. I would expect the output to be `int` and `array` respectively, instead I get `int` `int` with the two calls that instantiates the template functions respectively with an int type and an array type:

Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
inline static void constexpr SetCoordinates()
{
    if (std::is_array<T>::value)
        std::cout<<"array\n";
    else
        std::cout<<"int\n";
}


int main()
{
 int a = 6;
 std::array<int, 4> arr = {1,2,3,4};
 SetCoordinates<decltype(a)>();
 SetCoordinates<decltype(arr)>();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::is_array` is not `std::is_std_array`, it just checks *raw array type*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`std::is_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_array)  does not include the case of `std::array`; Rather, it only checks if the type is just a normal array type(i.e `T[]`, `T[N]`). Hence, your `if` statement lands in the false branch.

You have to provide a custom traits for the `std::array` for this to happen:

```
#include <type_traits> // std::true_type, std::false_type, std::is_array
    
template <typename T> struct is_std_array : std::false_type{};
template < typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_std_array<std::array<T, N> > : std::true_type { };

template <typename T>
inline static void constexpr SetCoordinates()
{
    if (std::is_array<T>::value || is_std_array<T>::value)
        //                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-->and check
        std::cout << "array\n";
    else
        std::cout << "int\n";
}
```

[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Pffa8T9an)

Answer (score 1):

In this simple case I can use `std::is_integral`, providing the template function is called only with those two types:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
inline static void constexpr SetCoordinates()
{
    if (std::is_integral<T>::value)
        std::cout<<"int\n";
    else
        std::cout<<"array\n";
}


int main()
{
 int a = 6;
 std::array<int, 4> arr = {1,2,3,4};
 SetCoordinates<decltype(a)>();
 SetCoordinates<decltype(arr)>();
 return 0;
}
```